# Multiple Server Versions who needs to supported by one mobile App Version

Tags: android, ios, server

My question is literally a duplication of

[Mobile strategy: How to handle this server-client version permutation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573693/mobile-strategy-how-to-handle-this-server-client-version-permutation#)

but this question is fairly old and rather ignored. Maybe back in 2017 there are new results?
This is a problem with the different deployment behaviors of mobile apps and business applications: You don't typically have multiple versions of a mobile app in an appstore. Rather you have one app version. But .. what to do if you have to support multiple server version?

I'm also highly interested in research papers / hints.

Comment: You may only have one app version in the store but your users may have different versions. Not all users update their apps to the latest version.

Comment: This statement: "Thus for compatibility reason, we have to make sure that each client version works with each server version" doesn't make sense to me.  If client 2.1 is released when the server is on server version 1.1, then it doesn't matter if client 2.1 works with server 1.0 because it will never use server 1.0.  Similarly client 2.0 will never call server 1.1 because it was built against server 1.0.  Each server version must work with each client version that is configured to call it, no more.

Comment: It's not a problem to show a message in the app "your app is out to date, please update", but on the other hand it's a problem to say "please update your server" because the update process of the backend is complicated in the most cases. We can't just say "okay, app v1.1 just works with server v1.1", this will end up in multiple app versions in the app store. As a developer we don't see any problems in this, but as a end user, this would be frustrating.

Comment: OwnCloud seems to have the same problem: One App and multiple server versions. They uses if-Statements for code execution for different Server versions. In the future the code will be bloated with if-statements.